# SCALAR output after creating executable from perl script

Tags: perl

I have a working perl script that I want to create an executable from. I used PAR::Packer and

```
pp -o try.exe run_scenarios_1.1.pl
```

to create the .exe file. Now, when I run the .exe in cygwin with

```
User@PC ~/my_perls
$ ./try.exe
```

I get the following output and the program cancels:

```
User@PC ~/my_perls
$ ./try.exe
SCALAR(0x60103eac8)
```

Here is my minimal code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;

my $export_complete_path = "C:/Prog/Cygwin/home/User/my_perls/test/";
my @test_file = read_file($export_complete_path."Do_Test.txt");
my @combined_data = read_file($export_complete_path."Do_Test_Copy.txt");
### Take the original file and add the current test data
push (@combined_data, @test_file);
### add data to file
open my $newfile, '>', $export_complete_path."combined.txt" or die "\nError: Unable to create in $export_complete_path\n";
write_file($newfile, @combined_data);
```

It's my first bigger perl program and the first time I use the PAR::Packer.

Do I need to force the packer to do something special?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code that _works_ with pure Perl and _doesn't work_ when compiled into an .exe file. This is what we call a [mcve].

Comment: The posted code works in perl, but after packaging it to an .exe file it does not anymore.

With the .exe the script stops after the "SCALAR", with the .pl file it keeps on working.

Comment: I tried exactly your posted code in Perl and as try.exe. Both give the same output. There's nothing wrong with the code you show, so I guess it's something in the code you don't show. ;-)

Comment: Okay, I understand, I added the full code.

Comment: I changed my code to a minimal version, that triggers my "SCALAR"-Problem.

Comment: print STDERR all over and debug

Comment: I added a print "STDERR $variable;" every time i set a variable or array. Here is the difference from running cygwin to exe:
cygwin:
`# new file: #
GLOB(0x600077ee0)
# written: #
GLOB(0x600077ee0)`
exe:
`# new file: #
GLOB(0x60104b090)SCALAR(0x600f5aa50)`

I print directly after open and directly after write. The write is missing in the exe, but the open also already looks different?!